# How to wrap multi-nested elements in another multi-nested element

Tags: javascript

how can you wrap multi-nested elements into another multi-nested element? For example if I have the following:

```
let div = '<div data-v-921b5f16="" class="v-input v-input--is-label-active v-input--is-dirty theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted"><div class="v-input__control"><div class="v-input__slot"><div class="v-text-field__slot"><label for="input-74" class="v-label v-label--active theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Reference</label>' **WRAPPED ELEMENT** '</div></div><div class="v-text-field__details"><div class="v-messages theme--light"><div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div></div></div></div></div>';
```

How can I wrap the following in the placeholder where it says WRAPPED ELEMENT?

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
      <div id="c">
      </div>
   </div>
</div
```

Comment: I am not getting what is the issue here? Why can't you simply concatenate the following the placeholder like `let div = '<div data-v-921b5f16="">' + '<div id="a">...</div>' + '</div>'`

Comment: Do you have to identify the `**WRAPPED ELEMENT**` bit dynamically??

Comment: Well lets just assumed it's any element that exists within the DOM that has multiple nested divs inside of it.